# How to code SQL for a filter via list of checkboxes

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, search, filter

So I am about to make a webpage where users can check/uncheck from a list of filters, and then see the products relevant to them.

Similar to Wayfair.com, but MUCH smaller scale.

(ex: https://www.wayfair.com/Floor-Lamps-l6238-c416504-O76363~Modern.html)

I use parameterized queries in PHP -- should I code the logic for this in PHP or SQL?

---

Here is a mock of my table:

[image: My Table]

A1, A2, A3, would be something like "product type" (desktop/tablet/mobile)

B1, B2, B3, B4, would be like "app type."

---

EX1)

So, if I wanted to search for **Ipsum** it should show up if:

- I have A1 **and/or** A2 checked
- **AND** I have B3 checked.

---

EX2)

If I wanted to search for Lorem:

- I would have to have A1 checked
- **AND** I would have to have B1 **and/or** B2 checked

---

**NOTE** -- This issue would be very easy for me to solve if I could use dynamic queries where I generate a query string based on what is checked, and then execute the dynamic query string. HOWEVER, I cannot use dynamic queries due to security concerns. So this makes me think that I should consider doing the filtering logic in PHP, instead of SQL? But if there is a SQL way, that sounds like it would be more efficient...

Comment: What security concerns do you believe there would be with dynamic queries? They are the bread and butter of sites that have options just like you've described.

Comment: @Dave From my research on sites like OWASP, while dynamic queries CAN be done safely, parameterized queries offer much more architectural security? So if possible, I would like to avoid dynamic queries. That said, based on my (limited) knowledge of SQL, I too am unable to see an elegant solution that doesn't employ dynamic queries.  OWASP link: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Escaping_Dynamic_Queries

Comment: You're going to be using PDO (right?) and prepared statements (right?) so you should not need to be concerned with any escaping or anything of the sorts. Besides, you're going to check your incoming data to make sure it is what you expect (right?).

Comment: dynamic queries and parameterized queries are not mutually exclusive. You can still have dynamic queries with parameters. To make it secure, you just have to build your query so that you are adding columns to the where clause from a pre-determined list (e.g. not relying on user input for the column names) and then you can setup parameters for the values passed over from the user. The query that you prepare is just a string and can be dynamic up until that point.

Comment: The only other option, if your table really only holds 1/0 values, would be to use binary options to determine which flags are set. Which would probably still be a little dynamic up to a point.

Comment: if you are going to write a catch all query in sql server, add this to your reading list: http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/ (uses dynamic sql, execution is parametrised, not concatenated)

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I think I understand what you're saying about making dynamic queries that aren't dependent on user data -- and I think that will work just fine. Thank you

Comment: Another option is to use some sort of ORM. They build the query dynamically as you add in more and more conditions, but can be easier in that you can just loop over the user information and keep adding `$query->orWhere('col', $val);` over and over.